# convert text file into graph

Tags: python, graph

I am currently attempting to do problem 81 from project euler. How can I convert a txt file with a stream of numbers into a dictionary storing a graph?

[image]

Now, my plan is to take the text file with numbers separated by commas (They are not 'pre-grid' so it's not in an 80 x 80 structure) and convert them into a dictionary where I can store them as a graph

where all the vertices are connected vertically and horizontally

So take the items in the txt file (using a 4 x 4 grid as demo):

```
"a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p"
```

convert them into a dictionary storing a graph

```
graph = {
    a: b, e
    b: a, c, f
    c: b, d, g 
    etc etc ...
}
```

from which I will use djkstra's algorithm to find the minimal path since the values in the txt file are actually integers and have weight values

P.S
is this a good way to tackle the problem?

Comment: To answer your PS: No. You're overthinking it.

Comment: As this task is only to find a minimal sum, not the actual path: ```0)``` write unit tests ```1)``` store the integers in an array. ```2)``` just use a brute-force algorithm for starters. That means, check every possible path. ```3)``` think if there is a better algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: @Melon The graph (80x80) has 6400 nodes and the brute-force algorithm is highly ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problem 81 you can move only right or down. So you need a directed graph for your Dijkstra algorithm. If you use a dictionary as a graph each value (list) in this dict must have not more than 2 nodes (you can move only in 2 directions -> 2 neighbors). You can delete two first `if` blocks in the last piece of code of @AustinHastings. Otherwise you will move in 4 directions and will get a different result. Here is the solution for the example in the problem 81. I‘ve used the package `networkx` and `jupyter notebook`:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import collections

a = np.matrix("""131 673 234 103 18;
                 201 96 342 965 150;
                 630 803 746 422 111;
                 537 699 497 121 956;
                 805 732 524 37 331""")

rows, columns = a.shape

# Part of @AustinHastings solution
graph = collections.defaultdict(list)
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        if c < columns - 1:
           # get the right neighbor 
           graph[(r, c)].append((r, c+1))
        if r < rows - 1:
           # get the bottom neighbor
           graph[(r, c)].append((r+1, c))

G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(graph, create_using=nx.DiGraph)

weights = {(row, col): {'weight': num} for row, r in enumerate(a.tolist()) for col, num in enumerate(r)}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, values=weights)

def weight(u, v, d):
    return G.nodes[u].get('weight')/2 + G.nodes[v].get('weight')/2

target = tuple(i - 1 for i in a.shape)
path = nx.dijkstra_path(G, source=(0, 0), target=target, weight=weight)
print('Path: ', [a.item(i) for i in path])

%matplotlib inline
color_map = ['green' if n in path else 'red' for n in G.nodes()]
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'weight')
pos = {(r, c): (c, -r) for r, c in G.nodes()}
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, labels = labels, node_color=color_map)
```

#### Output:

```
Path:  [131, 201, 96, 342, 746, 422, 121, 37, 331]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the actual input file format. I assume it's 6400 integers separated by commas, with no newlines (or maybe with one newline at the end...). But it could be something different...

First, let's read them all in:

```
def read_numbers(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()

    numbers = []
    for s in text.split(','):
        numbers.append(int(s))

    return numbers
```

Now split the single long list of numbers into rows of 80 each. I assume your 4x4 example was meant to be like this:

```
a, b, c, d,
e, f, g, h,
```

So we'll just break the rows the same way:

```
SIZE_80x80 = 80 * 80
numbers = read_numbers('matrix.txt')
assert len(numbers) == SIZE_80x80, "Expecting 80x80 matrix!"

matrix = []
for index in range(0, SIZE_80x80, 80):
    matrix.append(numbers[index:index+80])
```

Now you have the numbers in a `matrix`, indexed by row then column. That is, `matrix[0][1]` would be 'b' in your 4x4 example. While `matrix[1][0]` would be 'e'.

Your question asks how to build a dictionary of neighbors. With the matrix available, just iterate over it:

```
# import collections
graph = collections.defaultdict(list)

for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for c, num in enumerate(row):
        if r > 0:
           graph[num].append(matrix[r-1][c])
        if c > 0:
           graph[num].append(matrix[r][c-1])
        if c < 80-1:
           graph[num].append(matrix[r][c+1])
        if r < 80-1:
           graph[num].append(matrix[r+1][c])
```

Comment: Cheers! However I am getting a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5870\n1096'"

Comment: Obviously my assumptions about the input file format were incorrect. You'll have to modify the `read_numbers` function to deal with multiple lines.